# Windows mobile user interface suggestions

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pocketpc

I will start new PDA project on the windows mobile and compact framework 2.0 or higher.
I need to design the new application user interface like IPhone, it should be smilar IPhone buttons, gradiend screens, colors, some thing like this. It seems i need to many images and backgrounds on the windows mobile application for achieving this.

I don't need to use default pocketpc UI elements, it's not useful for my project and me.
I need your some suggestions about the new pocketpc app user interface design.

Could you please share me your ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/IPhoneUI.aspx) will be of interest for you (iPhone UI in Windows Mobile). You may also want to look into [UI Framework for .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/uiframework) ([MSDN article describing some of the features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630622.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you for your advise Fredrik, i'm checking.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at:

http://fluid.codeplex.com/

and

http://www.beemobile4.net/

Answer (score 4):

I feel your pain.  Worse yet, I use Win32 and C/C++ for my WM apps, which none of the listed UI libraries even support.

The end result is that unless you buy UI components from someone else for this platform, then you will unfortunately have to write your own UI controls.  I had to do just that myself.    :/

There is more info [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191136/ui-components-for-windows-mobile-applications-net-compact-framework).

Comment: It seems, i will agree with you, thak you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at all these options, Fluid looks nice but the complexity of the code put me off. I've gone with a very basic approach (which fits my current needs) and I've written an ImageButton control

Comment: I agree with you Fluid seems complex too. I also developed a library for my project which is had mixed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630622.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/iPodTouchUI.aspx projects. I was good for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a vote for Resco. I been working with .NET for years but don't have any mobile or C++ experience. The Resco controls are not cheap but they made it vastly easier and cut my dev time by at least 50% and probably a lot more. In the scale of things the cost is nothing compared to developer wages and missed deadlines. No affiliation - just a happy customer :)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [Resco Toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx)